# How can I avoid a memory leak when initializing a map in the constructor of a class?

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, memory, memory-leaks

I would like to initialize a (pointer to a) `map` in the constructor of a class. The program I wrote compiles but fails at run time due to a segmentation fault. I can resolve the problem by allocation memory for the `map` dynamically but `Valgrind` informs me about a memory leak. How can I initialize the class correctly?

Here is an example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MemoryLeak {
   public:
    MemoryLeak(std::vector<std::string>& inp) {
        int i = 0;
        std::map<std::string, int>* tmp = new std::map<std::string, int>;
        for (std::string& s : inp) {
            //(*problem_map)[s] = i++; // Line 12: causes a seg fault
            (*tmp)[s] = i++;
        }
        problem_map = tmp;  // Line 15: memory leak
    }
    std::map<std::string, int>* problem_map;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> input{"a", "b"};
    MemoryLeak mem = MemoryLeak(input);
    for (auto const& it : *(mem.problem_map)) {
        std::cout << it.first << ": " << it.second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I uncomment `line 12` (and comment out `Line 15`), the program compiles but a memory leak seems to occur. Can somebody kindly tell me what I am doing wrong? How would a more appropriate constructor look like?

Comment: Why do you think you need a pointer to a map?

Comment: thanks, @NeilButterworth for your reply! I would later (in code I didn't mention here) pass on parts of the map to another instance of the class without copying the data.

Comment: @fabian The days of needing pointers for that are long gone. Because of move semantics, you can pass on the instance to another owner with constant time complexity, without having to copy it. Edit : and even if your specific use case needs a pointer, prefer a smart pointer like `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers and `new`,  there is a better way to do whatever you're trying to do

Comment: thanks for your comment, @FrançoisAndrieux! I am vaguely aware of these concepts, but I am currently working my way through [Accelerated C++](https://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-C-Practical-Programming-Example/dp/020170353X) and wanted to understand the material well before I learn new concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **segfault**:

Your pointer `problem_map` is uninitialized at line 12. 
That why the segfault. 
You doesn't need the `tmp` you can just do this:

```
problem_map = new std::map<std::string, int>;
for (std::string& s : inp) {
    (*problem_map)[s] = i++; 
}
```

Now for the leak, you have two choices :

1) Add a destructor, a copy-constructor and a copy-assignment operator (or make them deleted). See rule of [three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

```
class MemoryLeak {
   public:
    ~MemoryLeak() {
        delete problem_map;
    }
    MemoryLeak(const MemoryLeak& ) = delete;
    MemoryLeak& operator=(const MemoryLeak& ) = delete;
    MemoryLeak(std::vector<std::string>& inp) {
        int i = 0;
        problem_map = new std::map<std::string, int>;
        for (std::string& s : inp) {
           (*problem_map)[s] = i++; 
        }
    }
    std::map<std::string, int>* problem_map;
};
```

2) don't store a pointer, but the map

```
class MemoryLeak {
   public:
    MemoryLeak(std::vector<std::string>& inp) {
        int i = 0;
        for (std::string& s : inp) {
            problem_map[s] = i++;
        }
    }
    std::map<std::string, int> problem_map;
};
```